# Is it possible to make \pnode obey swapaxes?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

### Background:

We can represent a point with `(*<value> {<algebraic expression in x>})` syntax where the ordinate `y` is obtained by evaluating `<algebraic expression in x` for the given abscissa `x` that is equal to `value`.

As there is no the complementary syntax `({<algebraic expression in y>} *<value>)` where the abscissa is evaluated based on the given ordinate, I try to use `swapaxes`.

Unfortunately, `\pnode` does not accept this `swapaxes` option.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\def\y{2*x}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psset{swapaxes}
    \qdisk(*1 {\y}){3pt}
    \pnode(*-1 {\y}){A}
    \qdisk(A){3pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Question:

Is there an instant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSTricks version 2.44 (`2013-06-24`), see `texdoc pst-news13`, has the coordinate option `**` which does this:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(0,0)
    \pnode(**{2*y} -1){A}
    \qdisk(A){3pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]